# Codeigniter how to upload the resize image or thumb ONLY

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new with `CodeIgniter` and want to resize the image first before saving to my database and local storage using `move_uploaded_file` i was able to resize using below code but how to I access the resized image and upload it using `move_uploaded_file` on PHP

```
$uploaddir = './images/post/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($value1."-".$date."-".$_FILES['file']['name']);

$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = $uploadfile;
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['width']     = 350;
$config['height']   = 1;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['master_dim'] = 'width';

$this->image_lib->clear();
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand that essentially what you are doing is uploading the file to the temporary directory and using the locally stored file to generate a resized image.

**So for better or worse your image is already on your server.** Thus:

Your order of operations is wrong. You need to use the upload library to first bring the image on to your server, and then you can use that file location instead of the temporary name, to resize the image. With Codeigniters image lib you can make it so that the resized image overwrites the original. To do so you change `$config['create_thumb'] = false;` and resize will target the source/original image.

More on that setting here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#CI_Image_lib::resize

If you really want to go your route (which isn't great because you don't have the protections the upload library offers) turn `$config['create_thumb']` to false as I've said before OR note that the thumb file should be the temp name + `_thumb` + whatever extension.

See thumb marker here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#preferences

Answer (score 1):

When user submits a file(form must have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute for this to work):

1. file is being uploaded to [configured](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads) server directory `upload_tmp_dir`
2. uploaded file properties are stored in `$_FILE` array: original name, mime type, temporary name ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php))
3. after script ends temporary file is being deleted

So, if you want to store only resized image, you can process directly temporary file using absolute path in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` property.

Comment: So i have to replace my source_image to $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']?

Comment: Generally CodeIgnitor has a file upload module: 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

I suggest to combine two modules as described here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939503/i-want-to-resize-uploaded-image-in-codeigniter-but-it-is-not-working